# Comparing values from 2 data frames in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I currently have 2 data frames as follows

```
DF1
1 Name1
2 Name2
3 name3

DF2
1 Name1 Loc1
2 Name2 Loc1
3 Name3 Loc1
```

I am trying to add a column to DF1 where the value equals the location of corresponding name in DF2.

I've tried numerous nested statements and if statements and can't seem to get the column to generate with names in it.

Comment: What do you mean by *location* in *(...) equals the location of corresponding (...)*?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mcve]. Furthermore, please, show what you have tried so far and what the expected result should look like. Thank you.